# upgrade only mongoDriver in SpringBoot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

Good morning,

I have a set of hundreds of microservices based on Java8 SpringBoot 2.7.8 and 2.4.5 on which I need to update the MongoDriver for project needs (the target version will be 4.7 compatible with MongoDB 6)

For access to external systems these microservices use custom libraries built on SpringBoot...

a library to communicate and query MongoDB, a library for utility, a library for Rest , a library for communicating with RabbitMQ etc...

The first thing that came to my mind is to update all the libraries and microservices to SpringBoot 3.1 (using the new spring-boot-starter-parent) and Java17

However, it is a time consuming and tedious job.

Is there a different way to carry out this update without updating the entire SpringBoot framework of all libraries and Microservices and still guaranteeing the functioning of the microservices?

An example that I had thought of: can I only update the mongoDB library that comes with the driver to version 3.1 and Java17 and continue to use it by importing it into the pom.xml of the microservices even though they use version 2 of Spring and Java8?

In this scenario, could I have incompatibility problems or runtime problems given the use of different versions of Java and SpringBoot to create the different Jars?

Thank you.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.7.1+ uses Mongo driver 4.6.1 that is partially compatible with MongoDB 6 ("not all new MongoDB features are supported").  Have you tried if it is enough for you?  Have you tried to upgrade just the driver?